# p5 javascript object classes switching roles

Tags: javascript, object, p5.js, game-development

I have this program that I have created and It runs perfect, but when I add the enemy class into my code. The player class takes on all of the color properties of the enemy class, and the enemy class takes on all of the properties of the player class. I don't know how to fix it. Really the main thing that is wrong is the circle class and the enemy class switch colors when I run it. Like I will change the color in the circle class and the enemy class will be the one that changes to said color.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Arrow Keys</title>
    <script src="../p5/p5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../p5/addons/p5.dom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../p5/addons/p5.sound.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        #score {
            display: block;
            color: #333333;
            padding-bottom: 1%;
            font-family: arial;
        }
        div{
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;

            /* This centers our sketch horizontally. */
            justify-content: center;

            /* This centers our sketch vertically. */
            align-items: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="score"></div>
        <script>
            function setup() {
                createCanvas(windowWidth-100, windowHeight-100);
                frameRate(-1);

                enemy = new Enemy();
                circle = new Circle(); 
                enemys = [];

            }

            function draw() {
                background(51);

                enemy.show();
                circle.show();

            }


            function Circle() {
                this.x = width/2;
                this.y = height/2;
                this.xspeed = 0;
                this.yspeed = 0;
                this.size = [30,30]
                this.radius = this.size[0]/2;
                this.score = 0;

                this.show = function(fillColor = "#FFFFFF") {
                    this.playerEllipse = ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.size[0], this.size[1]);
                    this.playerEllipse.fill("#FFFFDD")
                    this.playerEllipse.stroke("#FFFFDD");
                }
            }

            function Enemy() {
                this.x = random(1,200);
                this.y = random(1,200);
                this.xspeed = 0;
                this.yspeed = 0;
                this.size = [30,30];
                this.radius = this.size[0]/2;

                this.show = function() {
                    this.enemyEliipse = ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.size[0], this.size[1]);
                    this.enemyEliipse.fill("#FF0000");
                    this.enemyEliipse.stroke("#FF0000");

                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the player class ?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]? For example your question is not related to keyboard input, so can you get rid of that code? Start with a small example that just shows two rectangles based on classes.

Comment: player class is Circle() class and the enemy class is Enemy()

Comment: And yes Kevin I tried to simplify it and give more clarity.

Comment: @JustinBattaglia You have a mistype in the  Enemy class. Could you show me how are you using enemy.show(), circle.show() and how are you instantiating ? Ty